# How to create a TRUE or FALSE column based on regexpr() findings in R?

Tags: r

I am searching through a column to find a pattern,

```
reg <- regexpr("pattern", Data$column1)
View(reg)
```

reg gives me some numbers as the following:

```
   [1]  43  15   2  11   
   [19]  22  28  20  11
   [37]  32  11  32  20
```

but I want `reg` to be 0 or 1 based on whether "pattern" has been found or not in `Data$column1` .

When I used `grepl,`

```
 reg <- grepl("pattern", Data$column1)
    View(reg)
```

I only got TRUE values in `reg`. Not FALSE values. But I want both in the column. If it finds the pattern store TRUE in `reg` if not store FALSE. 
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: @MrFlick I see no reason why that shouldn't be an answer. (Unless you just left a comment and then went searching for a duplicate)

Comment: @MrFlick but I also want the false value in the column. But reg only has true in the column.

Comment: @Gworld Your comment doesn't make sense to me. How about you actually create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gworld That's not a reproducible example. It sounds like your pattern is matching every row. As you can see it works fine with: `x<-c("ant","dog","ant"); grepl("a",x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grepl()` instead which will return a TRUE/FALSE value. You can use `as.numeric()` to turn it to 0/1 if you want.

See the `?grep` help page for all the different pattern finding functions.